# Play sound on remote RPI using script executed by SSH

Tags: ssh, audio

I have a python script that plays a `.wav` file on the speakers.

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('a.wav')
```

This works correctly if I execute the script on my local machine.

However, if I push the script on my remote Raspberry PI (along with the `.wav` file) and execute it through an SSH session, the sound doesn't come out of the speaker plugged on the Raspberry PI.

I already had some question related, when I needed to open the web browser on the remote Raspberry PI device, but it doesn't seem to fix it.

I tried

```
python3 my_script.py
```

and

```
DISPLAY=:0 python3 my_script.py
```

None of them do play the file on the raspberry PI's speakers.

For info, `omxplayer a.wav` does play the file on the remote speakers properly. But I do not want to call a 'shell' command for that, I'd like this to be done through a python script.

Comment: It seems you don't have a proper Python3 setup on your RPi.

Comment: What happens if you put the path to the program before both Python3 and the Python script?

Comment: @Seamus Just did a fresh reinstall of Raspbian, with no luck. Andyroo no luck either with that

Comment: For the record, Xorg has nothing to do with sound, so adding `DISPLAY=:0` to your command will never have an effect on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems the `playsound` doesn't work properly on Raspbian (tried on a fresh install, with no luck).

However [PyDub](https://linuxhint.com/play_sound_python/) worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Congratulations, Arthur! +1  Please mark your answer as the "accepted" answer - it's more likely to help others, and you are the ONLY one who can do so.

Comment: I'm aware of how Stack Exchange works, however I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer ;-)